# Does it make sense to use messaging queues in a non-distributed application

Tags: java, architecture, messaging

So I'm planning on writing an application that would lend itself well to a producer/consumer pattern. I was thinking of building out my own producer/consumer framework but then thought about message queues something I use extensively at work. I'm not a 100% sure that a messaging queue would be the right approach considering that the multiple modules of the application I am writing need to run on a single server as its a client/controller of sorts for that particular host.

What are the pros and cons of using messaging queues for a non-distributed application? Has anyone used it in this way before?

Thanks, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Message queues give persistence in case of failure. Is tht important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "message queues" do you mean an external message server?  My below answer assumes that is what you were aking about.  If you are just asking about the more general architectural approach of having modules communicate partially, or in full, via in-memory-messages instead of method calls--yes sometimes this can be very nice.  Classes like guava's EvenBus facilitate a design like this nicely: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained

On the one hand I generally try to discourage people from using JMS message queues when a simple queue data structure would suffice.  Sometimes I feel that JMS is an inter-process communication tool that has one-to-many (topics) and one-to-one communication channels *which happen to be named queues*.  Yes their access pattern is similar to that of a queue, but the more important characteristic, it seems to me, is their point-to-point messaging capability.  So an unfortunate name that I think sometimes causes people to use a jackhammer (JMS) when all they need is a screwdriver (java.lang.Queue).

On the other hand there are exceptions to any rule. I can't recommend, off hand, a java.lang.Queue implementation that is thread-safe and persistent during server restart (an often needed feature when people are considering JMS).  I'm sure there are some.  Find a few and compare them to JMS.  Weigh business needs, time constraints, possible future design/requirements, etc.   I have implemented one myself before and it turned out quite nice (and was faster than sending messages over the network to a remote JMS server)-- but only you can say if this is right for your situation.

I suppose you could always defer the decision by having the modules of your app communicate through a messaging-like interface of your own which uses java.lang.Queues internally for now, but JMS later if you find that you *need* it.  Though be careful here too-- adding unnecessary abstraction early is sometimes a burden that turns out not to be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I was thinking more along the lines of an architectural approach of modules communicating through in-memory-messages. Completely agree JMS would be a jackhammer, and I took a look at EventBus and I think it's something worth exploring.